# What does this query do ?

Tags: mysql

There's a part of query i don't understand it

Can some explain it please?

`(@a:=concat(@a,schema_name,'<br>')`

If we consider that `schema_name` return all the databases name

Is it loop or what i can't understand

Comment: It's a lousy bit of code IMO. This kind of data display issue could be handled in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, that is a statement in a `select`:

```
select @a := concat(@a, schema_name, '<br>')
from t;
```

If `@a` is initialized to `NULL`, then this returns `NULL`.  Typically, it would be initialized to an empty string (`''`).

If so, it constructs a string containing all the values of `schema_name` followed by `<br>`.  So, if the table contained:

```
schema_name
     a
     b
     c
```

The result would be `'a<br>b<br>c<br>'` in the `@a` variable (and MySQL will return this result as well).

In MySQL, you would normally use `group_concat()` for this purpose.

Comment: Ok , but can you tell me what does `:=` do ?

Comment: `a<br>b<br>c<br>`  will be `@a` value ?

Comment: @dragon . . . Yes.  The `:=` assigns values to variables in a `select`, `update`, or `delete` statement.

Comment: is there any loop in this query ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704555/mysql-what-does-this-query-mean